# How to share caption, location and image together on my iOS app same like as Instagram in Facebook iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, facebook, instagram, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I want to share the caption, image and location to `Facebook` the same as `Instagram` doing it using Facebook iOS SDK. I want it to be exactly like in the screenshot from Facebook below.

I tried with `FBSDKShareLinkContent` class and its method `FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:shareContent delegate:self`.

I want something like this image:

[image]

I spent many hours on this but I can't find same like `Instagram`.

Comment: i also face the same issue when try to add location with text,image sharing.

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Has anyone solved it please help